# Find duplicates in array in cobol

Tags: cobol

I have a requirement where I need to check duplicate records in an array and merge them in one single record.

For finding duplicates in array, I have written below pseudo code:

```
PERFORM VARYING I1 FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I1 > MAX-TABLE-COUNT           
    PERFORM VARYING I2 FROM 1 BY 1 UNTIL I2 > I1-1      
        IF FIELD1(I1) = FIELD1(I2) AND FIELD2(I1)= FIELD2(I2)   
            PERFORM MERGE-RECORDS
        END-IF  
    END-PERFORM     
END-PERFORM
```

Here the issue is if the field1 and field2 are present 4 times, then I have to merge All four records into 1 record. Could you please suggest how it can done.

Comment: What does "merge" records mean in this context?  Are there other fields aside from FIELD1 and FIELD2?

Answer (score 1):

Here are two suggestions. Change them as you see fit.

The code is written for COBOL 85. Depending on your compiler and system there will be other, possibly better, means to do the same.

---

The following code will **not** maintain the original order unless the table is already ordered by `ascending` `field1` and `field2`. The table is compacted by restoring only the merged records.

```
   main-line.
       *> procesing before merging records
       perform sort-records
       *> procesing after merging records
       stop run    *> or exit program or goback
       .

   sort-records.
       if max-table-count > 1
           sort sort-file ascending field1 field2
               duplicates in order
               input procedure release-records
               output procedure return records
       end-if
       .

   release-records.
       perform varying i from 1 by 1
       until i > max-table-count
           release sort-record from table-entry (i)
       end-perform
       .

   return-records.
       move 0 to max-table-count
       perform return-next-record
       move sort-record to ws-record
       perform return-next-record
           *> first two records are in place for following loop
       perform until end-of-input
           if ws-field1 = sort-field1
             and ws-field2 = sort-field2
               perform merge-records
                   *> duplicates are dropped after merging
           else
               perform move-record-to-table
                   *> merged or unique record is saved
               move sort-record to ws-record
           end-if
           perform return-next-record
       end-perform
       perform move-record-to-table
           *> last record is saved
       .

   move-record-to-table.
       add 1 to max-table-count
       move ws-record to table-entry (max-table-count)
       .

   return-next-record.
       return sort-file
       at end
           set end-of-input to true
       end-return
       .

   merge-records.
       *> whatever is needed
```

---

The following maintains the original order and compacts the table by removing the merged duplicates. Note, in the code comments, that `marked` records are to be deleted, while `unmarked` records remain.

```
   main-line.
       *> procesing before merging records
       perform find-and-remove-duplicates
       *> procesing after merging records
       stop run    *> or exit program or goback
       .

   find-and-remove-duplicates.
       *> find and merge duplicates
       perform varying i from 1 by 1
       until i > (max-table-count - 1)
           if field1 (i) (1:1) not = high-values
               *> only compare unmarked records
               add 1 to i giving j
               perform varying j from j by 1
               unitl j > max-table-count
                   if field1 (i) = field1 (j)
                     and field2 (i) = field2 (j)
                       perform merge-records
                       move high-values to field1 (j) (1:1)
                           *> mark for deletion
                   end-if
               end-perform
           end-if
       end-perform

       *> remove duplicates
       perform varying i from 1 by 1
       until i > max-table-count
         or field1 (i) (1:1) = high-values
           *> find first marked record
           continue
       end-perform
       *> if there are no marked records, control
       *> will pass to the end of the paragraph
       *> and the table will remain unchanged

       if i not > max-table-count
           perform varying j from i by 1
           until j > max-table-count
             or field1 (j) (1:1) not = high-values
               continue
           end-perform
           *> i points to a marked record
           *> j points to an unmarked record
           *>   or is greater than max-table-count
           *>   which would occur if all marked records
           *>   are at the end of the table

           *> loop to compact the table
           perform until j > max-table-count
               move table-entry (j) to table-entry (i)
               add 1 to i
               add i to j
               perform varying j from j by 1
               until j > max-table-count
                 or field1 (j) (1:1) not = high-values
                   *> find next unmarked record
                   continue
               end-perform
           end-perform
           subtract 1 from i giving max-table-count
               *> adjust count for removed records
       end-if
       .

   merge-records.
       *> whatever is needed
```

If the records are in sorted order, the code may be made more efficient.